# Addinng a string utilizing a quote in django raw query

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I want to include a string as a query and the string would contain spaces so I would need to make use of quotes.

But this is giving me error that it is expecting another parameter.

```
  ModelName.objects.raw("select * from tablename where city='%s' and state=%s",params=['San francisco', 'Los Angeles'])
```

This the error that is produced

```
 error:  Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Comment: Why are you using `'%s'`? The documentation _explicitly_ advises against that...

Answer (score 0):

In the section [Passing parameters into raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) the documentation explicitly warns against putting quotes around the `%s` (i.e. writing it like  `'%s'`), and also states that it will make you vulnerable to SQL injection. Moving further it should not matter that your string contains spaces, the `%s` are not used for string formatting, rather they are later replaced with `?` by Django and are used to make a query using *prepared statements*.

Hence your query would simply work if you write:

```
ModelName.objects.raw("select * from tablename where city=%s and state=%s",params=['San francisco', 'Los Angeles'])
```

Also you don't even need raw queries for this. You can simply write something like the following which would be equivalent:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(city='San francisco', state='Los Angeles')
```

Comment: I exclude the quotes, it did not work even though it did not show any error. But the query did not produce any result. What should I do.

Comment: @SMev Is there really a row in your table where the column `state` has the value `"Los Angeles"`? And is there really a row in your table where the column `city` has the value `"San francisco"` with a small f? If not, that would explain getting no results.

Comment: @SMev as stated by BoarGules do check that. Also it might be saved as `San Francisco` with a _capital_ `F` in the database in your query you have written a small `f`.